Mi paginador crece demasiado conforme lleno más datos, ¿cómo puedo acortarlo?
Tengo un problema con mi paginador, crece demasiado el número de páginas conforme meto registros llevo ya 1000 registros y las paginas ya no caben en la pantalla, quisiera saber como puedo hacer un paginador mucho más adecuado, que quiza me muestre la pagina 1 , la actual y la última, talvez así:

<< 1...34...678 >>

O algo que me parmita acortar, ¿Me podrían ayudar?, he tratado con funciones aunque la verdad no creo haberlas hecho bien, y la verdad sigue sin darme, el paginador funciona excelente solo tengo ese problema.
aqui se ve el paginador, funciona bien el problema son los datos vcuando tengo mas de 500 datos las paginas crecen tanto que no dejan ver nada


 <div class="paginador">
        <ul>
            <?php 

              if($pagina != 1){

            ?>
            <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo 1;   ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-backward-fast"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1;      ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-backward"></i></a></li>
            
            <?php
        }
                for ($i=1; $i <= $total_paginas ; $i++) { 

                    if($i == $pagina){

                        echo '<li class="pageSelected">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                    }else{
                          echo '<li><a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';

                    }
                    
                    
                }

                if($pagina != $total_paginas){

            ?>
            
            <li><a href="?pagina=<?php  echo $pagina + 1;  ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-forward"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="?pagina=<?php  echo $total_paginas;     ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-forward-fast"></i></a></li>

        <?php }  ?>
        </ul>
     </div>





</section>


Lo usual es poner las primera páginas, un " ... " y luego las últimas. Mira cualquier sitio como http://myduckisdead.org/

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! es necesario aclarar que hay tantas paginas?? usualmente los sistemas tienen buscadores... como vas a saber que hay en la pagina 345???

Replicar tu ejemplo es complicado. Yo podría poner como hago yo para hacer lo que necesitas, pero claro, no sería exactamente tu código y tu tendrías que entender la lógica de lo que se ha hecho... Si quieres me dices e intento explicarte como hacerlo, pero si aceptas, necesito que pongas una captura de como luce tu paginador ahora mismo

OCHOA claro que si amigo ya voy a poner el paginado

me podrias ayudar con ello que depronto se muestre la pagina 1, la actual y la ultima de resto que funcione pasando paginas normal

Hola Daniel, cuando hay comentarios de más de un usuario, para responder a uno puntual para que se entere, es necesario hacerlo así, ejemplo, @OCHOA

Gracias Marcos. @danielhernandez y eso que es  eso es lo menos parecido a un paginador que mis pobres ojos hayan visto. No se supone que tendría que ser algo como: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ??? y te lo digo porque si no tienes un paginador, pueda que se te complique aun más mi ejemplo

@OCHOA exacto asi esta solo que lo tengo con una clase css que se transparenta si no lo estan usando, la cuestion es como puedo lograr hacer eso?

@danielhernandez ponga una captura de su paginador, quiero verlo. O deme el link de su web, lo que sea para ver la estructura de su paginador... Una vez yo tenga esa captura, hago la respuesta

@OCHOA vale dejame tomo la captura necesita es el codigo

@danielhernandez quiero ver su paginador, quiero ver algo como esta imagen quiero una vista previa de lo que tiene para ver si puedo llegar a dejarlo así, se entiende???????

vale entiendo mira @OCHOA

podrias proporcinar codigo solo de la partde del paginador actual para asi tratar de ayudarte

@Chritian Javier Ulloa Carmona claro que si claidad ya mismo te lo comparto, ya lo puse en el enunciado

Voy a intentar decirte como conseguir lo que quieres. Por favor, analiza bien lo que yo ponga y antes de preguntar, analiza otras veces más a fin de intentar entender. Iré comentando mi código y todo se base en este esquema

// En algún lado define el numero de items por cada pagina, yo lo hago en el config
define('ITEMS_BY_PAGE', 6); // Esta es una variable global

$totalProfiles = $querys->totalProfiles();
/* Debes saber el total de resultados, en mi caso perfiles de usuarios.
Esta query no es más que un (SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalProfiles FROM tuTabla + filtros)
en donde tu obtienes un único dato, el total de registros de tu vista (para mi caso el index)*/
$totalProfiles = $totalProfiles[0]['totalProfiles']; // Esta variable guarda ese dato

if ($totalProfiles > 0) {
    $actualPage = false;
    $isMobile = $helpers->isMobile(); // Esta funcion me permite ver si el usuario está en movil (no la voy a explicar)
    if ($isMobile){
        $items = ITEMS_BY_PAGE; // La variable global en movil es igual a 6
    }
    else{
        $items = 12; // La variable global en PC es igual a 12
    }

        if (isset($_GET["page"])) { // el get por pagina
        $actualPage = $_GET["page"];
    }

    if (!$actualPage) { 
        $start = 0;
        $actualPage = 1; // toma el valor de la pagina actual
    } else {
        $start = ($actualPage - 1) * $items; // Es el inicio de registros de la vista actual
    }

    $profiles = $querys->getProfiles($start, $items);
/* Obtengo los perfiles pero con un limite en base a lo que quiero mostrar.
Para mi caso es algo como 
(SELECT u.id, u.user, p.name FROM tusTablas u INNER JOIN otrasTablas WHERE tusFiltros 
ORDER BY tuCampo DESC LIMIT ?, ?) estas dos ultimas variables son los filtros de tu paginador */
    if ($profiles) {
        $rowsProfiles = $profiles[1];
        $totalPages = ceil($totalProfiles / $items); // Esta es la ultima de mis paginas
        $startPage = (($actualPage - $items) > 0) ? $actualPage - $items : 1; 
/* Esta página es la que se mostrara a la izquierda, antes de los tres puntos */
        $endPage = (($actualPage + $items) < $totalPages) ? $actualPage + $items : $totalPages;
/* Esta pagina es la que se mostrara a la derecha, antes de los tres puntos */




/* A partir de acá yo muestro mi resultado en HTML y obvio eso ya lo sabes hacer */




<div class="container divPagination">
    <ul class="pagination">
    <?php
            if ($totalPages > 1) {
                if ($actualPage != 1) { 
/* Estas dos líneas obligan a pintar las flechitas del extremo izquierdo */
    ?>
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="/?page=<?php echo $actualPage-1; ?>">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php
                    if ($startPage > 1) { // Si la página es la 1
    ?>
        <!-- Pinto mi primer página (la 1) con link al index, en mi caso no quiero 
             ver sitio.es/index?page=1 por eso lo pongo al root del dominio -->
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="/">1</a>
        </li>
        <!-- Luego de eso muestro los famosos tres puntos (deshabilitados) -->
        <li class="page-item">
            <span class="page-link">...</span>
        </li>
    <?php
                    }
                }
             /* Este for tu ya lo tienes, es el que pinta todos los 
                resultados del paginador, lo vamos a obviar */
                for ($i = $startPage; $i <= $endPage; $i++) {
                    if ($actualPage == $i) {
    ?>
        <li class="page-item active">
            <a class="page-link" href="#"><?php echo $actualPage; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php
                    }
                    else {
    ?>
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="/?page=<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <?php echo $i; ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php
                    }
                } // Acá termina el for
                if ($actualPage != $totalPages) {
                    if ($endPage < $totalPages) {
              /* Estas dos líneas hacen exactamente lo contrario a las del start */
    ?>
        <!-- Luego pinto los tres puntos de la discordia -->
        <li class="page-item">
            <span class="page-link">...</span>
        </li>
        <!-- Pinto mi última página (la 13) con link al 13 (obvio) -->
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="/?page=<?php echo $totalPages; ?>"><?php echo $totalPages; ?></a>
        </li>
    <?php
                    }
    ?>
<!-- Por ultimo pinto las flechitas de la derecha -->
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="/?page=<?php echo $actualPage+1; ?>">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

Y ahí acaba mi paginador. Funciona perfectamente (al menos en mis sitios xD) y se ve genial. En móvil yo hago que se vea al 100% y en PC que se vea centrado y a un tamaño decente, eso es CSS/Estilo y es cosa tuya.
PD: Al final del paginador es necesario cerrar algunos if de los resultados obtenidos pero los quité porque confundirían y no vienen al caso, es obvio que tu eso ya lo tienes porque ya tienes un paginador, así que solo necesitas ocultar unos resultados y mostrar los tres puntos locos 

Diablos, tardé más en ir por un refresco a que alguien vote negativa la respuesta quien sabe porqué, ya que no tiene valor de decir que rayos tengo mal

gracias bro voy a hacer todo muchas gracias amigazo

hey bro lo de tu posdata es lo que necesito como oculto algunos resultados y muestro los punto de hecho ese es mi problema bro nada mas que eso, intente tu solucion y sigo igual

No, nada que ver, el paginador no tiene nada que ver con las llaves de cierre de los IF de arriba. Es obvio que tu ya tienes todo, solo necesitas meter los tres puntos. Es que el PD no es para ti, ese es para algunos puritanos que puedan salir diciendo que no cerré los primeros IF y todo eso, pero repito, esas llaves de cierre no tiene nada que ver con el paginador como tal. Todavía fui claro en decir: LEE y ANALISA antes de preguntar por algo que nada que ver...

de todas maneras muchas gracias bro acople tu codigo al mio e hice unos arreglos para el mio y funciono, de verdad te agradezco mucho bro

Esooo, me alegra que te sirviera. Una lástima que alguien voto en negativa mi respuesta, pero esto, servirá de mucho a otros... Y puedes poner el resultado final en tu pregunta por favor???

es practicamente el mismo paginador solo que con tus arreglos bro, gracias a ti logre lo que queria no hubo un cambio grande, solo consegui la solucion que necesitaba bro
